# JSON Schema to validate multiple similar objects inside an array

Tags: json, jsonschema

What keyword would I use in a JSON Schema if I want the elements of an array (which are all objects) to all follow the same schema?

Example:

```
"data": 
[
    { //validated
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Bob",
      "ready": "Not Ready"
    },
    { //validated
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Steve",
      "ready": "Ready"
    },
    { //not validated, missing "ready"
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Ted"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify the "data" object as type array and indicate the required elements in each item.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "data": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "ready": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "id",
          "name",
          "ready"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "data"
  ]
}
```